# How to set the value of an arbitrary pixel in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to modify the rgb value of each pixel inside ffmpeg.

I need to implement the following function:

`A[x + expr_1][y] = expr_2`

where x and y are the current sampled pixel, A is the input frame whose pixel need to be modified and expr_1, expr_2 are two independent expressions.

I tried using the geq filter but it seems there no way to set the value of a pixel other than from that currently sampled. For istance, the function p(x,y) only returns the value of the pixel at the specified location, but doesn't allow to set a value for that pixel. In other word, ffmpeg seems allowing only something like:

```
A[x][y] = expr
```

Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to set the value of a specific pixel?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is there a way to tell ffmpeg to set the value of a specific pixel?*

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf geq=r='if(eq(X,45)*eq(Y,651),NEWVAL,p(X,Y))' out.mp4
```

This will set the R channel's value for (45,651) to NEWVAL and relay all other pixels.

To check if a more generalized expression is possible, you should illustrate your requirements with actual `expr1` and `expr2`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunatly i don't think it solve the problem. Expr1 e and expr2 are not well defined yet, but they will surely depend on X and Y variables. So, say expr1 = X + 1, then the if condition will never be true since X is not equal to X + expr1 = X + (X + 1) for any X.

Comment: The geq won't allow you to address a specific pixel, but you can set the value for one, using the form in my answer. You have to reformulate your expressions in terms of the current sample e.g. if you want to set value of (12,34) to the value of (42,24), you would set `p(X+30,Y-10)`